# receiving style and dynamically applying it to elements selected with class, using Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm making a web service with Vue.js. What I'm trying to do is to change styles of elements which receive from parent component's property. For example:

(there are omitted lines)

**Parent component**

```
<template>
<div>
    <child v-bind:styles="styles"></child>
<div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components: { child },
    data() {
        return {
            styles: { width:'100px', height:'70px' }
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

The `width` and `height` of `styles` object can be changed, i.e. decided by anyone who use Parent Component.

**Chlid component**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="iterDiv" v-for="(item, index) in arr" v-key="index">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Child',
    props: [ 'styles' ],
    data() {
        return {
            arr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

And the Child Component is consist of iterated elements which have a class `iterDiv` for selection like `document.getElementsByClassName('iterDiv')`.

Now, I want to change Child Component's div elements, having `iterDiv` class name, style with `styles` dynamically.

Is there any way for it? Thanks.

If there is a answer already, I missed it and let me know it. I will delete this question.

Comment: `<div class="iterDiv" v-for="(item, index) in arr" v-key="index" :style="styles">{{ item }}</div>`

Comment: @ittus Okay! It works! thanks